# font in the caption

Tags: captions, bold

I need also in the figures and tables caption, the title be in bold not the description of them.
I mean "Figure 3" in bold but the description "this is a new and beautiful image for every one like that....." ordinary font.
I  use these commands, it works when  the caption is  not too long,

```
\usepackage[compatibility=false,labelfont=it,textfont={bf,it}]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=bf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a **compilable** document, not just fragments

Answer (score 6):

For "the title [of the caption to] be in **bold** [but] not the description of them", i.e., if an upright font shape needs to be employed, you should issue the instruction

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}
```

and *not* issue a `\captionsetup` directive.

If the caption title should be in ***bold italics*** and the caption text in *ordinary italics*, you should state

```
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it]{caption}
```

Don't use the `compatbility=false` option. The package's user guide states that "this option is neither recommended nor supported since unwanted side-effects or even errors could occur afterwards."

Comment: And how do you change the font in the referenced text? I would like to see Figure 1 italiced

Comment: @skan -- Please clarify: Are you asking a question about the appearance of the material that shows up in a cross-reference to a figure or table, or is the question about the appearance of the captions of the figures and tables?

Answer (score 4):

From your question, I gather that you want two things for your caption: Label should be in bold, text should be normal text.

From your code, I gather that you haven't quite decided on what you want. As pointed out by Mico, you don't need to use both `\captionsetup{}` and optional arguments when loading the package. Placed in the preamble like this, they would do the exact same thing. You could of course use `\captionsetup{}` later on in your document, to change how the caption should be for a single float, like figure or tabular.

Besides, you seem to be setting both the `labelfont` *and* `textfont`, when relly you just want the `labelfont` changed. If you want to remove changes that was put in earlier, and go back to the ordinary font, use `normalfont`. Example:

I also don't see why you overide the compatibility check. It is not recommended. From the documentation of `caption`, section 6, *Package support* you will find the following:

> You can override this compatibility mode by specifying the option
>
> `compatibility=false`
>
> when loading the caption package. But please note that using this option is neither recommended nor supported since unwanted side-effects or even errors could occur afterwards. (For that reason you will get a warning about this.)

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A short caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A longer caption, just because sometimes, well, you're kind of stuck with them, even though you really shouldn't.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont}
\centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption{A short caption, no bold label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Minor quibble - "I also don't see why you remove the compatibility-check." -- Should that be "... provide ..."? :-)

Comment: thank you @Mico, I changed the wording to reflect that package-documentation. I agree, it could be misunderstood.

Comment: @Mico we just keep stealing each others answers :P

Comment: And how do you change the font in the referenced text? I would like to see Figure 1 italiced.